# Java HashMap with Object as value along with anything that extends it?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap that takes a string as a key and an object as the value, in this case a class I made called ItemBuilder. I can put another class that extends it as a value, but I can't use any of the methods that the class has. Why is this?

```
HashMap<String, ItemBuilder> registry = new HashMap<String, ItemBuilder>();
registry.put("ZEUS_BOLT", new ZeusBolt());
registry.get("ZEUS_BOLT").testLog();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you check documentation for Map, you will see that a for `Map<K, V>`, method is deplared as `V get(Object key)`. This means that `get` returns object of type specified in variable declaration, in your case `ItemBuilder`.

I'm assuming that `ItemBuilder` doesn't have a `testLog` method, it is defined in `ZeusBolt`. From `get` you are getting a `ItemBuilder` object.

If you want to be able to call `testLog` you need cast it to a proper type like so:

```
ZeusBolt zeusBolt = (ZeusBolt) registry.get("ZEUS_BOLT");
zeusBolt.testLog();
```

In case you have objects of different types in the map and want to iterate over all of them and do approriate operation based on type, you might be interested in `instanceof` operator to check if variable is of given type:

```
ItemBuilder itemBuilder = registry.get("ZEUS_BOLT");
if (itemBuilder instanceof ZeusBolt){
    ZeusBolt zeusBolt = (ZeusBolt) itemBuilder;
    zeusBolt.testLog();
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to grab an item from the registry based on user input, how would I do so? Say if I had a ZeusBolt and a Sword class, both extending ItemBuilder, would I have to have if statements checking for every type?

Comment: @JordanBaron Yes, if you want to call different methods you have to do that.